# Keep checkbox state after shutting down app

Tags: kotlin, state, android-preferences

i have app with multiple checkboxes, which gets disabled after checking all three of them. The problem is, when i close the app, the state doesnt presist. My code:

```
private fun setCheckedChangedListener() {
        listOf(binding.checkTaskOne,binding.checkTaskTwo,binding.checkTaskThree).forEach {
            it.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _ , _ ->
                if(binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked && binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked && binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked) {
                    binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled = false
                    binding.checkTaskTwo.isEnabled = false
                    binding.checkTaskThree.isEnabled = false
                    binding.textView2.setText(R.string.splneno)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried experimenting with the onDestroy function and Prefrences, but i dont exactly know how it works.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        save(binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked())
        save(binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked())
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

    }

    private fun save(boolean: Boolean) {
        val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with (sharedPref.edit()) {
            putBoolean("check", true)
            apply()
        }
    }
```

Comment: its usually better to add a listener to these checkboxes and update shared prefs everytime the state of these checkboxes change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to do. Most important thing is, you do not load saved preferences at all. Also, you save preference every time at the same name - it won't work, every setting must have separate name to let runtime distinguish between them.

I have modified method which does saving and add one which does loading. I call it in onCreate() method, which is called on the beginning.

By the way, there are still some things to improve, like avoid repetition of getting Shared Preferences handler and moving name of every preference for example into constants section, to avoid making mistake during typying them in load and save methods usages.

Code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        [...] //things like initialize binding, etc.

        binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked = load("checkTaskOne")
        binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked = load("checkTaskTwo")
        binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked = load("checkTaskThree")

    }

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        save("checkTaskOne", binding.checkTaskOne.isChecked())
        save("checkTaskTwo", binding.checkTaskTwo.isChecked())
        save("checkTaskThree", binding.checkTaskThree.isChecked())
    }

private fun load(name: String): Boolean {
        val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return false
        return sharedPref.getBoolean(name, false)
    }

    private fun save(name: String, boolean: Boolean) {
        val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putBoolean(name, boolean)
            apply()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Two things: is it possible to keep the checkbox disabled too? i tried it with the save function, e.g. save("checkTaskOne", binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled()) and it still keeps being active. Second, when i fully close the app in emulator, its still the same. Is it because i have it in fragment and i call it in "onViewCreated" instead of "onCreate"? sorry for stupid questions, I'm a beginner.

Comment: 1) Of course, it is possible to store state of another View's property, just use another name for this, in mentioned case for example "checkTaskOneIsEnabled"). Don't forget to use new name in the loading section too. 

2) I checked my code again, this time in fragment - loading in onViewCreated, saving in onDestroy method and it still works. You should try code debugging. I had error leading to result you have - I forgot to assign binding property in whole fragment module and it gave me kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException. Check logcat.

P.S. Please, don't forget to rate my post ;)

Comment: so, it finally works! but the is enabled check still doesn't.  like you said, I made the save("checkTaskOneEnabled",binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled()) and binding.checkTaskOne.isEnabled = load("checkTaskOneEnabled"), but still doesn't stay disabled if I shut down the app, all checks are checked, but it doesn't disable the checkbox until I re-check one of them. BTW, would you happen to know how would I recreate the fragment in alarm receiver, so it would clear the checkboxes in specific time? in short, how to recreate the fragment inside the alarm receiver?

Comment: My bad, i figured it out, it works normally. but the question about reinitiating the fragment still stands, if you would happen to know how.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I didn't see it before. What are you doing in this alarm receiver? Show some code

Comment: Sorry, i didnt see it until now. Well, for now, I'm just generating a noti in the alarm receiver, but I wanted to make it so the checkboxes reactivates and uncheck when the alarm receiver procs. but I don't know how to call it from the receiver class. should I edit this and add the code in the previous question or how should I implement it?

Comment: To be honest, public project repository would be best option for me to help you. It would give me the same work environment like you have and I would be able to test project and find solution to your problem. Give me link to repo if you can (on Github for example)

Comment: https://github.com/Schimanski-java/MindHelper here you go. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: also, for some reason, even tho i tried to change the flags in the NotiUtils, the app keeps crashing on emulators higher than API 31, don't know why.

Comment: I solved your problem with unability to "reload fragment" from level of BroadcastReceiver, but telling more precisely, you just wanted to modify your checkboxes state - reset them.

Below are the modified parts of code. I used mechanism of so-called Broadcast intents. Feel free to ask anything about it. 
https://pastebin.com/tGFSD6PB

I will come back to solve latter question soon.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it in the emulator, it seems that it only works when the app is running tho. Is it only the problem of the emulator or is it just if the app is running?

Comment: I found solution for your problem with app crashes on API versions 31+. You have to specify Pending Intents mutability flag in constructor (last parameter). This intent does need to be mutable, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE is enough. But it was still not working, although it should. According to fix written there: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69152986/revisions I had to increase version of androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx to 2.7.1, from your 2.5.0. After those changes, app seems to runs fine on API 31.

Comment: And about last question - I will check it soon.

Comment: i dont know why, but it still doesnt work. I changed the implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1', but still keeps crashing, at least on the emulator... don't know if its just something which is embedded within the emulators but it still shows me this "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.mindhelper: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent."

Comment: could it be because of the setting of the alarm in main activity?

Comment: Did you specify mutability flag as last parameter of all PendingIntent constructor invocations? It won't work without it, this is the main fix. The one with changing work-runtime version is just side-fix, necessary to apply the main one, because Google changed something in SDK also.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to change it in the main activity intent. Works now, thanks!

Comment: still have the problem with app not refreshing the checkboxes when the app is closed. Btw. Ive changed the saving preferences from "onDestroy" to "onStop", because it seemed like it didn't sometimes save the states, do you think its a problem? It shouldn't be, since its just for saving the prefs right?

Comment: also, seems that the setting of alarm isnt correct either, because the alarm probably duplicates, creating multiple intents at once. is there a way to stop this? probably to make on start and canceling the alarm and setting it again?

Comment: Do you still have mentioned problems? Sorry for long time without reply, I've been busy.